# telebot+python. Не получается передать название города через строку Телеграмм дальше в запрос погодника через API

Tags: python, api, telebot

После получения текста в @bot.message_handler (content_type = ['text']) символы (название города) должны сохранится в функции. И потом их как-то нужно передать словарю запроса (в значение ключа "q"):
query = {
"q": <НАЗВАНИЕ ГОРОДА>,
"lang":"eng",
"units":"metric",
"mode":"json"}

Я уже как только код не писал, все равно не выходит. Насколько я понимаю, то тут нужно поиграться с областью видимости переменных.

Comment: а для чего вам запрос?

Comment: По запросу (по названию города) я получаю данные о погоде